# How to correctly install Xdebug to use with PHPUnit?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, composer-php, xdebug

I'm trying to install Xdebug but it seems don't work.
I explain: I want to use PHPUnit but I have this message:

> No code coverage driver is available

I searched and I found that would be a problem with Xdebug. I change in the php.init in WAMP and I have this:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension="D:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.35/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="D:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

In composer.json, I have:

```
 "require-dev": {       
    "symfony/debug": "^3.4.17",
    "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^4.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
```

In the AppKernel.php:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
```

I don't know how do...

Comment: Hi what Ide are you using?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Hi @delph49! Can you execute `php -i` and check whether xdebug is listed in the output?

Comment: It's not listed in the output